# XMLBeam parsing

Tags: java, xml, parsing, xpath

I am unable to properly read a XML file with XMLBeam:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<soap:Body>
    <ns1:storeTokenResponse xmlns:ns1="http://recurring.services.adyen.com">
        <ns1:result>
            <additionalData xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true" />
            <alias xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com">ALIAS</alias>
            <aliasType xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com">Default</aliasType>
            <params xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true" />
            <pspEchoData xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true" />
            <pspReference xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com">PSPREFERENCE</pspReference>
            <recurringDetailReference xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com">RECURRINGDETAILREFERENCE</recurringDetailReference>
            <redirectType xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true" />
            <redirectUrl xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com" xsi:nil="true" />
            <result xmlns="http://recurring.services.adyen.com">RESULT</result>
        </ns1:result>
    </ns1:storeTokenResponse>
</soap:Body>
```

with given Java class:

```
  public interface PaymentResponse {

   @XBRead("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:storeTokenResponse/ns1:result/ns1:alias")
   String getAlias();

   @XBRead("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:storeTokenResponse/ns1:result/ns1:recurringDetailReference")
   String getRecurringDetailReference();

   @XBRead("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:storeTokenResponse/ns1:result/ns1:pspReference")
   String getPspReference();

   @XBRead("/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/ns1:storeTokenResponse/ns1:result/ns1:result")
   String getResult();

}
```

I was doing it like this :

```
final PaymentResponse paymentResponse = new XBProjector.onXMLString(xml).read(PaymentResponse.class);
Assert.assertTrue("ALIAS",paymentResponse.getAlias());
```

And yes, proper XPath is `ns1:alias`, as I've tested.

But looks like XMLBeam is not properly recognizing the values.
Can anyone help, please ?

Comment: Where are the namespaces created for those prefixes?

Comment: Can't understand you, sorry.

Comment: `ns1`, `soap` prefixes there in the xpaths, but not seen the namespaces for them.

Comment: they're included in  the xml , that's the way XMLBeam works

Comment: I mean to say that those hard coded. What if xml uses different prefixes?

Comment: It's fixed one, a standard payment third party company provides those.

Comment: You should really not relay on the prefixes to be fixed.

Comment: "ns1:alias" hm, alias is in a namespace with no prefix, so I'm not really sure that's correct, try to omit prefix on the innermost elements in the XPaths.

Comment: Looks like it was a bug on xmlbeam library. Author released 1.4.10 version to solve it.